# I think there is an issue with IDisposable example

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I implementing IDisposable correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136210/am-i-implementing-idisposable-correctly)

Hi,

I am referring this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) to check the use of IDisposable.

I see an issue in Dispose method here. In the code "disposed" is used only in the

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

method.

I believe it should be used before calling the "Dipose" method and correct implementation would be

```
public void Dispose()
        {
            if(!disposed )
            {
            Dispose(true);
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
            // take this object off the finalization queue
            // and prevent finalization code for this object
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

Am I thinking correct?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the implementation of `Dispose(disposing)` checks the `disposed` flag anyway, why bother doing it in the `Dispose()` method as well?

The only downside would be that `GC.SuppressFinalize` could be called multiple times if you call `Dispose()` multiple times - but that's harmless as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I think I should remove the check from Dispose(disposing)  and put it in "Dispose".

Comment: @Ram: No, that way the Finalizer might do something double and that is not always harmless.

Comment: But isn't it logical that we should not call "SuppressFinalize" if object is disposed? or "SuppressFinalize" is called once for that object.

Comment: Why do you think that?  The only efect would be to prevent `GC.SuppressFinalize` being called multiple times, if `Dispose()` was also called multiple times.  Are you perhaps over thinking this, what bug or behaviour are you trying to avoid with this change.

Comment: @Ben - Well , After looking in the code, I just thought about that if the bool diposed is there. It should be used more logically.

Comment: @Ram: I agree with you, though the assignment of the `Disposed` flag also needs to be there as well.  Incidentally, I'd use `Interlocked.Exchange` to set the flag, since it should only need to be invoked once per object, and classes that don't use it cannot very well offer thread-safe disposal [IMHO, *all* classes should offer thread-safe disposal, even if the only thing `Dispose` can do on a busy object is set a flag which is checked each time the object becomes un-busy, causing the object to be disposed at that time].

Comment: @HenkHolterman: If a class is going to have a finalize method, it too should check the flag (using `Interlocked.CompareExchange`).  Note that while `Finalize` shouldn't run simultaneous with `Dispose`, if the only reference to a finalizable object is held by an externally-defined finalizable object defined, and that outside object resurrects itself, it's possible for `Finalize` to get queued up to run while an object is still in use, potentially during its `Dispose` method.  Having the `Finalize` method test and set a flag with `Interlocked.Exchange` will guard against that.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget to clear up any unmanaged resources.  Microsoft gives sample code here:

"Implement IDisposable Correctly"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737(VS.80).aspx

-Krip

Comment: Surely that would be handled in the `Dispose(disposing)` code. Isn't this question about when to call that method?