# Performance recommendations of millions objects creation

Tags: c#, performance, .net-3.5

My code has to generate millions object to perform some algorithm (millions objects will be created and at the same time 2/3 of them should be destroyed).
I know that object creation causes performance problems.

Could someone recommend how to manage so huge amount of objects, garbage collection and so on?

Thank you.

Comment: See if you can avoid creating them in the first place. Failing that, see if you can make them a value type so that you might get away with not making a separate memory allocation for each object.

Comment: I'd recommend you write the code as simply and elegantly as possible, then start measuring the performance of the code. Who knows, it may turn our you don't need to optmize yet! If performance does start dragging, you need to measure exactly where the slowness is, and based on that, remove the bottlenecks. You could try avoiding to allocate many small objects, but fewer large objects. If you have very small objects like Points, use C# structs to store those.

Comment: @Jon every object has array of int, array is ref type.

Comment: If that objects are really short-living, GC will take care of them efficiently, they won't ever leave the first generation. An allocation profile you're describing is quite typical for functional languages, and .NET memory management is already reasonably tuned for it by default. If your objects lifespan is longer, consider pre-allocating and reusing them. Anyway, any optimisations should be done only after profiling an ad-hoc implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating a bit on my "make them a value type" comment above.

If you have a `struct Foo`, then preparing for the algorithm with e.g. `var storage = new Foo[1000000]` will only allocate one big block of memory (I 'm assuming the required amount of contiguous memory will be available).

You can then manually manage the memory inside that block to avoid performing more memory allocations:

- Keep a count of how many slots in the array are actually used
- To "create" a new `Foo`, put it at the first unused slot and increment the counter
- To "delete" a `Foo`, swap it with the one in last used slot and decrement the counter

Of course making an algorithm work with value types vs reference types is not as simple as changing `class` to `struct`. But if workable it will allow you to side-step all of this overhead for an one-time startup cost.

Comment: This will probably work, but will force @garik to do some complicated memory management himself => lots of complicated, buggy code. I'd see if .NET GC can take care of it without further help first. Only do performance optimization when you **know** it for a fact that have to.

Comment: @Elad: The memory management is summed up in three lines, I wouldn't call it complicated. And the suggestion stems from the fact that the general-purpose memory allocators (no relation to the GC) built into modern high-level languages are *notoriously* slow for a variety of reasons. Slow + millions of calls = bad recipe.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you. Still, I wouldn't start looking for a solution, complicated or not, until there's a performance issue in practice.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible in your algorithm then try to reuse objects - if 2/3 are destroyed immedietly then you can try to use them again.

Comment: no, serious benchmarks showed that reusing of objects is often more expensive in presence of generational garbage collection than not reusing them. That is if you have to save the references to the objects in data structure.

Comment: @jmg tested, I did not get any time benefits, except a memory usage.

Comment: @garik: Just to be sure I and everybody else doesn't missunderstand you, you tested reusing object and it didn't give you any performance benefits?

Comment: @jmg  because of additional actions to be performed to manage reusing and these actions are more time consumed than creation. otherwise this code should be refactored to perform more lightweight reusing. thank you Jmg. Intuitively I understand that it should be faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement `IDisposable` interface on the type whose object is been created. Then you can implment `using` keyword and write whatever logic involving the object within the `using` scope. The following links will give you a fair idea of what i am trying to say. Hope they are of some help.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/interfaces/article.php/c8679

[Am I implementing IDisposable correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136210/am-i-implementing-idisposable-correctly)

Regards,

Samar