# When is StreamWriter disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, finalizer

I have a small class I threw together to implement a quick logger.  I composed it with a private `System.IO.StreamWriter` which is instantiated in the constructor.  Because the way I'm using is prevents me from implementing a `using` block, I added a finalizer and called the StreamWriter's `Dispose()` method in it.  However, when executing, that finalizer throws an exception because the StreamWriter has already been disposed.

> System.ObjectDisposedException - Cannot access a closed file.

I'm confused how this happened and I'm wondering if this means I don't need to worry about cleaning up the StreamWriter.  Here is my class:

```
public class TextFileLogger : AbstractTextLogger
{
    private const string LogPath = @"C:\";
    private const string LogFileName = "MyFile.log.txt";
    private readonly StreamWriter _writer;

    public TextFileLogger()
    {
        _writer = new StreamWriter($"{LogPath}{LogFileName}", true);
        _writer.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    ~TextFileLogger()
    {
        _writer.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        _writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Finalizers (aka destructors) run on a separate thread with no guarantees that other managed objects to which your object refer still exist.  The only things you should clean up in a Finalizer are unmanaged resources.  Make your TextFileLogger Disposable (implement IDisposable) and read up on the "Dispose Pattern" to get it just right.  If a class has no native resources (like yours) it **should not** have a Finalizer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: @Flydog57 - I'm familiar with implementing IDisposable, and have done so a few times before. I thought I could somehow just dispose of the StreamWriter inside my class without needing a using block. Since this is a quick and dirty, temporary thing, I will probably just need to new up the StreamWriter in every call to WriteLine so I can use it in a using block. This is awful, and will take about 14.5 times longer in execution time, according to my measurements, but for a short lived project, I'd rather take that performance hit than completely rearchitect everything.

Comment: Add a Dispose method for the things somewhere else in your code.  As long as it's in your normal code, you can dispose of it.  However, once you get in Finalizer code, all the "managed code guarantees" mostly get wiped off the table.  Finalizers are very easy to mess up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only things you are allowed to access in a finalizer are objects that are rooted (like static variables) or objects that derive from CriticalFinalizerObject.

The problem is the finalizer is not deterministic, it is allowed to run in any order it feels like. The problem you ran in to is because the text writer was finalized before your class.

You need to either just "hope for the best" and let the writer's finalizer to do the work or you need to refactor your code so your class is disposeable itself and that calls the stream writer's dispose method.

Comment: Would "hope for the best" be what my class would be doing if I were to simply remove the finalizer and leave the rest unchanged? I'm a bit surprised by your answer and the comments suggesting I implement IDisposable on my class. I'm familiar with that concept, and have done so before, but I thought there was some way to simply call an IDisposable's Dispose method without needing a using block to trigger it. I was hoping for a "has-a" instead of an "is-a" approach with this class, and implementing IDisposable is probably not an option here (the consuming code can't use a using block either).

Comment: Yes removing the finalizer would be the "hope for the best" option.

Comment: I decided to go with just implementing IDisposable, but not the pattern that includes the virtual method with the boolean disposing parameter and the call to GC.SuppressFinalizer. This project wasn't worth creating a whole base class hierarchy just for that.  Instead, I merely called the StreamWriter's Dispose() method from my class' Dispose() method, and I found a place to use my class in a using block (which was a bit hacky, but it works). It's basically like the accepted answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038321/c-sharp-idisposable-correct-usage-and-call/10038411#10038411

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on that simple version (in my previous comment's link)? I'm not sure why the only recommendation one can ever find is to implement that entire IDisposable base class with public and virtual protected methods, and make the call to GC.SupressFinalize(). It seems like the simple version should do the job, but I guess there's something wrong with it, since you never see it in docs or recommendations. I guess I'm still just hoping for the best. ;)

Comment: I think the advice to have a virtual method with a bool is a bad pattern, IMHO. Here is a good article that explains a better patern that you will never need to check for that bool again https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Comment: That is an amazing article, truly the one I've always hoped to find.  Thanks!