# What is the expectation of IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, using

I see a lot of code like this:

```
public class MyWcfService : IMySerciceContract, IDisposable
{
    private DatabaseOperations _dataAccess;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _dataAccess.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Where the class MyWcfService will be hosted in IIS or WAS, where no one will explicitly call Dispose on it. My thought is that it's pointless to have this class implement IDisposable, and you'd be better off wrapping the use of _dataAccess in a using statement. As I understand it, the expectation of a class that implements IDisposable is that a user of that class will instantiate it in a using block declaration. Is the above example bad practice considering no user will explicitly call Dispose? If we rely on GC to clean up as in the above example, does the GC even call Dispose, or just the finalizer?

Comment: Because you have a member that implements IDisposable you should ideally implement it...because your class has become the owner. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472304/is-there-any-benefit-to-implementing-idisposable-on-classes-which-do-not-have-re  ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956140/does-a-class-need-to-implement-idisposable-when-all-members-are-explicitly-dispo ..... and run FXCop to detect any IDisposable violations. Obviously, anything that uses your type needs to call Dispose (either explicitly or implicity via a using).

Comment: The GC knows nothing about Dispose or IDisposable. It just invokes the finalizer.

Comment: But in the case of a service class like this, where we dont even expect something to call Dispose, what's the point? Why would I implement IDisposable if I know no one will actually call Dispose? Wouldn't I be better off cleaning up _dataAccess myself within this service class?

Comment: This is why the "recommended" practice to is to call `Dispose(false)` in the finalizer. While the object *should* be disposed directly (usually by whomever creates said instance; in this case it should be the WCF host so the finalizer bit can be ignored happily), running-at-some-point-later is often better than running-never.

Comment: And I see you have created a WCF Service....the Dispose will be called when it's shutdown. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264746/wcf-service-and-idisposable-do-i-clean-up-managed-objects

Comment: Maybe WCF is a bad example, but I see it a lot where no one is wrapping a class like this in a using, and the developer of the class just punts off cleaning up higher up the call stack when many times no one is cleaning up further up

Comment: The point is that implementing IDisposable gives consumers of the code the OPTION but not the OBLIGATION to Dispose explicitly. If you don't implement the pattern, there is no such choice given to code which consumes your class.

Comment: You're not supposed to touch managed objects when Dispose is called by a finalizer (due to the non-deterministic GC you don't know what state those managed objects members are in)...thus it's primarily used to clean up unmanaged resources...e.g. native file handles etc. For the Dispose on it's own...you are meant to forward the Dispose call to your members....

Comment: because you have no idea if they are using unmanaged resources or not (that need cleaning up)...so you should just forward the call....if you don't then....you may get a performance hit...because then the object when it's collected will get added to the finalization queue....which adds additional overhead. IDisposable is a complex contract to understand....depends on your use.

Comment: @Baldrick that sounds like a fair enough rule of thumb, but then when do I make the decision to wrap _dataAccess in a using and when to implement IDisposable? If this class consumed something that operated on streams, it'd be a no brainer; i'd be wrapping it in a using.

Comment: "DatabaseOperations _dataAccess" is a class member, and is 'owned' by your class. It is IDisposable, so your class should be too. If _dataAccess were a local variable inside a class method, which you used and discarded within method scope, then a using block would be appropriate.

Comment: @Baldrick thanks, that's actually quite easy to understand. In a nutshell, design your classes as they need to be designed to accomplish the job, and handle disposing objects as it fits into your class design -members disposed via implementing IDisposable, local variables in a using, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DatabaseOperations _dataAccess" is a class member, and is 'owned' by your class. It is IDisposable, so your class should be too. And you should always implement the full standard dipose pattern for consistency.

If _dataAccess were a local variable inside a class method, which you used and discarded within method scope, then a using block would be appropriate.

As a rule, you want to code in such a way as to give the maximum degree of cleanup control to users of your code. That means being IDisposable if any of your members are. But for non-member IDisposable objects, then 'using' is the way to go.

Of course, the same then applies to consumers of your class. If they embed your class as a member field, they should make their class IDisposable. Otherwise, they can use 'using' with your class objects.. and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> ... , where no one will explicitly call Dispose on it. My thought is that it's pointless to have this class implement IDisposable ...

The point is, there is a lack of the finalizer which invokes `Dispose` in your code ..

> ... As I understand it, the expectation of a class that implements IDisposable is that a user of that class will instantiate it in a using block declaration ...

Usually, the expectation of a class that implements `IDisposable` is **there is something to dispose**. `using` is just a syntactic sugar, it's **not at all** the reason of implementing `IDisposable`.

> ... If we rely on GC to clean up as in the above example, does the GC even call Dispose, or just the finalizer?

The GC doesn't invoke `Dispose` automatically, so your would need to let the finalizer to invoke it.

```
public partial class MyWcfService: IMySerciceContract, IDisposable {
    private DatabaseOperations _dataAccess;

    public void Dispose() {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if(!this.disposed) {
            if(disposing) {
                _dataAccess.Dispose();
            }

            this.disposed=true;
        }
    }

    // so it make sense now .. 
    ~MyWcfService() {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    bool disposed;
}
```

If `Dispose` is not invoked by the consumer, the finalizer invokes it if necessary. See how to implement [[IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable.aspx)].

Comment: Not a bad answer, though I'm fully aware that we don't implement IDisposable for the sake of using statements lol. I grasp the concept of RAII well enough, my question was more about when to clean up disposable objects, and where that responsibility should be assumed.

Comment: @Didaxis: For **when**, I think ASAP when you are sure about that the disposable objects should not be used afterwards. If `_dataAccess` is acquired by the instances of `MyWcfService`, then `MyWcfService` should be responsible for `_dataAccess`. For **where**, is as the code I proposed which is as same as MSDN guided.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I marked Baldrick's answer as the correct one because I think it more directly addresses my question. Yours was helpful nonetheless! Also, what was up with the comment about my grammar? (just curious)

Comment: The fact that a class implements `IDisposable` doesn't mean there's something to dispose.  Rather, the expectation is that after an object's `Dispose` method has been called, there will not be any entities anywhere in the universe which are doing anything on its behalf to the detriment of any other entities.  An object which never asks any outside entities to do anything on its behalf will comply with that expectation even if its expose method does nothing, since after it runs there will (still) be no outside entities acting on its behalf.

Comment: @supercat: Ah, yes. It's true that the exposed `Dispose` method should do nothing with outside entities if it there wasn't any entity acquired at all. But I think it's the case that we can choose not to implement `IDisposable`, for avoiding artificial quantum entanglement ..

Comment: @KenKin: If a factory method will sometimes create objects which own resources, and transfer ownership to its caller (prime example: `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`, it should implement `IDisposable`.  The fact that it implements `IDisposable` does not create new responsibilities for the factory method's caller--those responsibilities are created by the fact that some of the created objects may own resources--but merely makes it easier for callers to carry out those responsibilities and increases the likelihood that they'll do so.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed, good example. By the concerning of design in some particular cases. I've revised for adding the word *usually*. Thank you for the conversation.

Comment: @KenKin: Factory methods cannot help but impose an obligation either on the authors of the objects being created to be tolerant of abandonment, or on the authors of the consuming code to call `Dispose`.  The work required for consumers to call `Dispose` from the beginning will generally be a tiny fraction of the work required to retrofit them to do so should a disposal requirement be added later in the development cycle.  Further, in the cases where designing consumers to support `Dispose` would add significant work, retrofitting will likely require *major* rework.

Comment: @supercat: Oops .. your last comment is not easy for me to read .. I guess what you mean is it'd be better to apply the dispose pattern from the begining of designing cycle if it's possibly necessary rather than to refactor afterwards. Right?

Comment: @KenKin: It's *much* better to apply it early; having a factory method return something that *doesn't* implement `IDisposable` essentially says that any future factories of products which do require cleanup should be segregated into a separate "universe".  Sometimes such segregation may make life easier for everyone concerned, but it should be a deliberate decision--not something one gets stuck having to do.